# How to generate a Maven dependencies.properties file?

Tags: maven, dependencies

A bit of context: I am writing an integration test using [Pax Exam](http://team.ops4j.org/wiki/display/paxexam/Pax+Exam) and I need to gather as much information as possible on the current Maven project. This is to reduce boilerplate code when loading the bundles of dependencies and of the working project itself.
For example, Pax Exam allows to gather the version of Maven dependencies by providing groupId and artifactId in the

*org.ops4j.pax.exam.MavenUtils.getArtifactVersion(String,String)*

method. To do it, the *META-INF/maven/dependencies.properties* file is looked up. The documentation says that such file is generated by a Maven plugin, but I really could not find  which.

Is there some way to produce such dependencies.properties file?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looks like this [depends-maven-plugin](http://team.ops4j.org/wiki/display/paxexam/Pax+Exam+-+Tutorial+1) does it.

Comment: It certainly does, Sir! Shame on me for relying too much on Google instead of the official documentation.